# HC-SR-04 with STM32

Tags: stm32

SR04 ultrasonic distance sensor with stm32.
When I use it with STM32 I use it as bothedge with input capture. I measure the HIGH time of the Echo pin.
I thought it was a mistake
When I used Ardiuno with pulsein, I was dividing the time by 29.1 .My measurement was accurate enough, but when I divide it by 29.1 when using STM32, the measurement is very wrong. I did it by dividing by 58.2. This time I got more accurate values. What is the difference?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's right to divide the duration of the echo pulse by 58, as described in the datasheet as follows.

> You can calculate the range through the time interval between sending trigger signal and
> receiving echo signal. Formula: uS / 58 = centimeters or uS / 148 =inch; or: the
> range = high level time * velocity (340M/S) / 2;

I tried to find an Arduino code which divides pulse duration with 29.1 or 29, I couldn't find it. Some posts computes the range by `range=(duration/2)/29.1`. I guess you've missed dividing duration by two. Double check your Arduino code, or post it if you want to be assured.